# Display scaling setting - difference between Gnome Tweaks and Gnome Display settings

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, display-resolution, gsettings, hdpi

Both gnome-tweak-tool and Display settings tools seem to offer a way to change the scaling of the display (See screenshot below), however it is not clear to me how they are related and which controls what. Also, they don't seem to be in sync.

Do you know What is the difference between these two tools?

Thanks!

[image: Gnome Tweaks and Gnome Display Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-Tweaks -- Font Scaling.. means size of the Font is Increased..

Fonts Scaling Factor set to 2
[image]

Fonts Scaling Factor set to 3
[image]

---

Display Settings.. is the scaling of all elements..

Displays Scale set to 100%
[image]

Displays Scale set to 200%
[image]

Based on your needs and resources both the cases are used..

Comment: Is there any performance reduction when using scaling other than 1 (100%)?

Comment: Yes.. system slows down. I never continued with other scaling bcoz of this issue.

Comment: So I guess using a lower display resolution is better than increasing the scaling factor since they both scale up windows and texts.

Comment: How is scaling in gnome-tweaks different than changing the font size in gnome-tweaks?